# Is it possible to declare a public field in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax, visibility

I wonder if it is possible to declare a **public field** in a Scala class. Scala normally generates a private field for `val` and `var` body variables/constructor parameters and getters/setters with the appropriate visibility.

I would like to know if it is possible to declare a public Java class *field* in Scala, not a getter.

---

*PS: Why would anyone need that? It may be useful e.g. for integration with Java frameworks relying on fields:*

```
class MyTest extends JUnitSuite {
    @Rule 
    val temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFilder() 
    // throws java.lang.Exception: The @Rule temporaryFolder must be public
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid Chris Martin is right. This is a duplicate question where the answer is "not possible" except if you mix in some Java.

Comment: All right, too bad. I edited the linked question so that it's easier to find looking for public *field*

Answer (score -1):

This is in response to the P.S, someone else has already posted an answer to the main question.

Because the logic behind using getters in setters (in java, for instance) is to "future-proof" your code, so that if your private field "x" somewhere down the line needs logic every time you get/set it, then you will just modify the method call and won't break any existing code that calls it. Whereas if you had just public fields and the need for logic arose, you would have to create getters/setters and then would break existing code due to changing the contract of the class. So scala just does this automatically to remove boilerplate code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In pretty sure OP is aware of this; the PS addresses why, despite your arguments, a public field may be necessary.

Comment: @Sivalion The PS is an explanation of why OP needs what they're asking for, not another question.

Comment: My apologies, thank you for the clarification